# Dragging a circle

Tags: svg, snap.svg

I am beginning to use snap.svg, and stuck in a probably simple question. I draw a circle, and want to let the user drag it around, and when the user stops dragging, I want to know the alert the final position of the circle.

I started with this:

```
var s = Snap("#svg");
var d = s.circle(20,20,5);
```

Then I created the following functions as drag event-handlers; I only need the drag-end event so I made the two other event-handlers null:

```
var endFnc = function(e) { 
    alert("end: "+e.layerX+","+e.layerY); 
}

var startFnc = null;

var moveFnc = null;
```

Then I installed the drag event handlers:

d.drag(moveFnc,startFnc,endFnc);

Whenever I tried to drag a circle, the end event fired, but, the circle did not move.

So I figured maybe I have to also create the drag move event (although I don't need it):

```
var moveFnc = function(dx, dy, x, y) {
  this.transform('t' + x + ',' + y);
}
```

Now the circle did move, but, not exactly at the mouse, but approximately 20 pixels at its bottom right.

I read the documentation here: http://snapsvg.io/docs  and there seems to be no explanation about how to create working drag events.

How does anyone get this knowledge?!

Answer (score 1):

After struggling for some hours to do this with snap.js, I finally discovered svg.js and its draggable plugin, with which it is so much easier:

```
var draw = SVG('svg');
var circle = draw.circle(10).attr({cx:30,cy:30,fill:'#f06'});
circle.dragend = function(delta, event) {
    alert(this.attr('cx'))
}
circle.draggable();
```

So, I switched to svg.js ...